# Why do people keep mispronouncing my name, Divine?

Tags: pronunciation, names, pronunciation-vs-spelling

My name is `Divine`--[like the English word](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=define+divine), "divine". There are no tildes, no accent marks, no umlauts, or funky letters like *æ*...nothing shady going on here. Yet every time someone reads my name, i always hear:

> "Now, excuse me if i mispronounce this...is it {'Divon', 'Devin', 'Div-in', 'Div-EE-nae' (yes, this one actually happened), etc.}...?"

I know my name isn't the most common name in the world, but it's an **English** word! I can understand if you have [a "regular-looking" name that has an abnormal pronunciation](http://s3-ec.buzzfed.com/static/enhanced/webdr05/2013/8/8/10/enhanced-buzz-27736-1375972128-17.jpg). I imagine the protocol there would be that you sound it out as best as you can first, *then* go for the funny pronunciations. But why do people reverse that order with my name?

To make matters worse, after learning how my name is pronounced, and its place in the dictionary, a large percentage of those people go on to *misspell* my name as `D`**e**`vine`!

Is there something about dialects, or the history of this word, or something, that makes people's brains start working when they read my name?

Comment: The singer Sade pronounces her name with two syllables; as does Beyonce. Desiree is pronounced with three syllables, as is Hermoine. With that as a backdrop, I'm not surprised that someone would try to pronounce your name with three syllables.

Comment: If you marry a Mr Right, I'd keep your maiden name.

Comment: *If* you're from a non-English-speaking nationality, it could also be that English speakers tend to pronounce it as a foreign word. Alternatively, you also refer to "a 'regular-looking' name that has an abnormal pronunciation": maybe people think that your name is "a 'regular-looking' name" but expect it to have "an abnormal pronunciation"?

Comment: @J.R. does Beyoncé only have two syllables? And Hermione only three?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: You're right, I miscounted. I was trying to show how the "e" at the end of some names doesn't function like a silent "e". My bad math aside, I only meant to suggest that names like the ones I mentioned might influence how someone reads _Divine_ as a name. It's only a theory. Nice catch, though.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I disagree!  If she marries a Mr. Right she should definitely take her hubby's name.  It would be a perfect pairing!

Comment: OP is male, pronunciations offered tend to be adjusted to not sound feminine.

Comment: That's an awfully articulate way of saying it's a girl's name.

Answer (score 12):

***Divine*** is not usually used as a name.  Names like [Devin (ranked 173 most common in the US)](http://www.behindthename.com/name/devin), [Devon (397)](http://www.behindthename.com/name/devon), [Davin (768)](http://www.behindthename.com/name/davin), [Devan (965)](http://www.behindthename.com/name/devan) are much more common names than Divine, which doesn't even rank in the top 1000 or even appear in any of the name databases I looked in.  Because people know that what they're trying to pronounce is a name, they're more likely to pronounce it like other names they've heard.

**We interpret new information based on past information**, assuming likelihoods based on past experience, in what is known as the [availability heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Availability_heuristic). Because most people have never heard "divine" used as a name before, most people who see your name for the first time probably try to associate the spelling with names that they do know.

Your name is presented **as a name**, but (as you point out) "divine" is usually heard **as an English word**.  Because people are viewing it as a name, they're not associating it with the English word.  You don't meet a person named Ryder and consciously think of equestrianism or a person named Allan and consciously think of wrenches or a person named Jasmine and consciously think of rice or tea.  You're viewing the names as names, and their alternate definitions as English words are processed subconsciously, if at all.

<sub>One possible, less likely, reason for the mispronunciation is that because "divine" is not a common name, people might actually think of its **definition as a word** and be hesitant to call you "divine" because of the various connotations the word carries with it.  They could worry about how you might react if they pronounce it `/dɪˈvaɪn/` if that turns out to be wrong.  They could think: *maybe she'll be offended by me giving a religious pronunciation of her name* or *maybe she'll think I'm giving a shallow compliment to someone I've just met*.</sub>

Comment: How do you know it’s a she?

Comment: @tchrist I don't.  But I had to use some sort of pronoun, and "she" is generally more PC.  Also, I was associating the name with Jasmine as well as various religious names like Hope, Grace, and Faith, which are generally female.

Comment: @tchrist Also, I've found that a lot of people assume that all unknown people online are male, so I assume they're female to keep things interesting. ;P

Comment: @user49633- I see what you mean...

Comment: @3nafish: FYI: It's not...

Comment: @3nafish: Also i just looked at your edit...are you kidding me...???

Comment: S/he sounds too good to be true.

Comment: The "lady" in whose company Hugh Grant was found on Sunset Boulevard back in 1995 used the name "Divine Brown", although that wasn't her real name, and no-one pronounced that wrong.  I admit that I am as stumped as the OP as to why people fail to pronounce her name correctly.

Comment: @3nafish, why do you make part of your answer so small-fonted that I have to copy/paste it into a text-box in order to read it?  Some of us no longer have the sharp vision of our youths, you know.

Comment: @user49633, if by “FYI: It’s not” you mean that you are in fact male, rather than female, then I believe that could be part of the reason. Rare as the name Divine may be in itself, I have at least heard of people called Divine before. But only women; never a man. People may be trying to figure out a way to make your name sound like a woman’s.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist I made it smaller because it borders on being a comment or footnote.  If you have trouble reading small text, a much faster way to increase readability it is to adjust your browser's default font size.  Hold the Control key on a PC (or the Command key on a Mac), and then press the +/= key.  To shrink the size again, do the same with the minus key instead of the plus.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it could be  due to people avoiding what they perceive to be "the mistake she must hear all the time". That is to say, they are going for a more nonsensical response and reducing the potential offense you might take. The other points seem quite valid, too.